# How to perform unit test for Binding.Scala?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala.js, binding.scala

I had written components using `Binding.scala` and they're working fine for me. Now I want to unit test them using `ScalaTest`. How to unit test them?

I had taken reference from [`Binding.scala`'s unit tests](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/blob/master/dom/src/test/scala/com/thoughtworks/binding/domTest.scala). However it's not working for me as `get` and `value`methods are not accessible.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: We can't see why it's not working if you don't share your "not working" code/tests...

Comment: Ops! It's really not possible to write such test in the user code:
```
 "TextElement" in {
      @dom val monadicDiv: Binding[Div] = <div>text</div>
      monadicDiv.watch()
      assert(monadicDiv.get.outerHTML == "<div>text</div>")
    }
```
because `Binding.get`/`Binding.value` is private/protected :(

Comment: @Imars; thanks for quick code. I want to do exactly same.

Answer (score 1):

In current version of `Binding.scala` (`11.8.1`) you can use this method for unit testing:

```
  "Comment" in {
    @dom def comment = <div><!--my comment--></div>
    val div = document.createElement("div")
    dom.render(div, comment)
    assert(div.innerHTML == "<div><!--my comment--></div>")
  }
```

Unfortunately, you couldn't write such (more performant?) tests:

```
  "TextElement" in {
    @dom val monadicDiv: Binding[Div] = <div>text</div>
    monadicDiv.watch()
    assert(monadicDiv.get.outerHTML == "<div>text</div>")
  }
```

because of `Binding.get`/`Binding.value` is private/protected.
I filled issue about this https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/issues/217

Comment: In the new [html.scala](https://github.com/GlasslabGames/html.scala), there is a `NodeBinding` type, which has a public `value` to access the raw HTML object. See  https://github.com/GlasslabGames/html.scala#getting-started